# How to return multiple values from a SET type column with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, set

I discovered now that `SET` is different from `ENUM` because it allows you to insert multiple values from a list.

So I try to return data from a set column.
First of all I create the table "Test_SET_vs_ENUM", than the "ColumnSET"('A','B','C','D') column and after that I inserted in the first row A,B,C

So I try to return data in different ways:

```
//First try
$sql=$conn->query("SELECT ColumnSET FROM Test_SET_vs_ENUM WHERE IDRow=1");
$result=$sql->fetch();
$conn->exec($sql);
foreach ($result as $content){
echo "Content: ".$content['ColumnSET']."<br/>";
}
```

And the output is:

Content: A

Content: ,

So I find out that a SET column stored data in form of FirstValue,SecondValue,3Value etc. So when I fetch the result the comma will "end" the array and I will have in the output only the first Value and his comma. This is confirmed by my second try:

```
//Second try
$sql=$conn->query("SELECT ColumnSET FROM Test_SET_vs_ENUM WHERE IDRow=1");
$result=$sql->fetchAll();
$conn->exec($sql);
foreach ($result as $content){
echo "Content: ".$content['ColumnSET']."<br/>";
}
```

This time the output was:

Content: A,B,C

But my goal is to have in output each different value, so I tryed this:

```
//Third try
$sql=$conn->query("SELECT ColumnSET FROM Test_SET_vs_ENUM WHERE IDRow=1");
foreach ($sql as $content){
echo "Content: ".$content['ColumnSET']."<br/>";
}
$conn->exec($sql);
```

The output is equal to the Second try.

So i'm asking you: How to get the values of a SET column and control each of them separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the comma seperated value, you need to [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it.

Then iterated over this exploded array using [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and show them separatly.

Do like below:-

```
foreach ($result as $content){
  $contents_ids = explode(',',$content['ColumnSET']);
  foreach($contents_ids as $contents_id){
    echo "Content: $contents_id<br/>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, you litteraly save me. Please specify that you are refferring to the Second try for others peoples. Have a nice day :3

Comment: @MattiaFrusca . glad to help you :):)